# Haskell sorting sublists by sum

Tags: list, haskell

Given a list of lists of integers in Haskell, how can you sort its sublists by the sum of the values in each sublist? i.e., if the list given is:

```
[[5,3],[1,1,1,1],[2],[10,22,0]]
```

The function's output would be:

```
[[2],[1,1,1,1],[5,3],[10,22,0]]
```

Note: The number of elements in each sublist does not matter, I just need the sublists ordered in ascending order by their sums. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you sorted lists by any other criteria before?

Comment: No, I haven't..

Comment: There is a function [sortBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) which will let you sort lists by custom criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
import Data.List

sortBySums :: (Ord a, Foldable t, Num a) => [t a] -> [t a]
sortBySums = sortBy (\l r -> (compare (sum l) (sum r)))
```

Comment: Pairing the sums with the lists is unnecessary: `sortBy (\xs ys -> compare (sum xs) (sum ys))` -- or, more neatly, `sortBy (comparing sum)`, using `comparing` from `Data.Ord`.

Comment: @duplode Thanks. I also came to that conclusion on my own after a few minutes away.

Comment: @Franky no, it is the `sum` that is working over any `Foldable`.

Answer (score 5):

All these methods work:

```
sortBySums = sortBy (\l r -> (compare (sum l) (sum r))) -- taken from pdoherty926
sortBySums = sortBy (compare `on` sum)
sortBySums = sortBy (comparing sum)
sortBySums = sortOn sum
```

`sortOn` has the advantage that it uses the Schwartzian transform, i.e. it only computes the sum once for each element.

Imports from memory, works without imports on https://www.haskell.org/

```
import Data.List(sortBy,sortOn)
import Data.Function(on)
import Data.Ord(compare,comparing)
```